# How to wait for another application (eXist-db) to start (using java), before interacting with it?

Tags: java, java-8, exist-db

I am currently working with eXist-db, and what I want to accomplish is executing command line script to start eXist-db (/bin/startup.sh) wait for it to create database so I can get collection from it.

```
    //start database
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + start);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    //get collection
    col = DatabaseManager.getCollection(URI + "/db", username, password);
```

I want to wait with the getCollection until database is created (can be called) , or after certain amount of waiting time if the database doesn't initialise I would like to kill it (lets say one minute at most). What is the best solution for this problem? Using sleep/wait several times and trying to call database?  Something like this?

```
    Process pr = null;
    try {
        pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + start);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            pr.destroy();
            return false;
        }
        try {
            dbDetected = initCollection();
        } catch (XMLDBException ex) {
            if (ex.errorCode != ErrorCodes.VENDOR_ERROR  ||
                    "Failed to read server's response: Connection refused (Connection refused))"
                            .compareTo(ex.getMessage()) != 0 ) {
                pr.destroy();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And as to killing part, I would like to confirm the assumption that storing the process and killing it using `Process.destroy()` function should be enough (basing it on assumption that the script for database is taking too long, in normal runtime, at the end of my application I would use provided eXist-db script /bin/shutdown.sh).

Comment: Check the process ID or the port seems reasonable to me. Depending on how far you want to go with a "health check", verify that you can login, even

Comment: I would prefer calling for collection, as this way i can later on add checks if for example the username and password was not denied  and in such case request new account information (currently i am checking only for existance of the database and stopping on any other error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using startup.sh, if you are running in embedded mode, then you can use ExistEmbeddedServer (or it might be called EmbeddedExistServer, sorry I am away from my computer for a few days) class from the test package instead.

I don't think you can use startup.sh directly for your purpose, as it creates a foreground process. Instead you should start eXist from your Java application as described above.

Comment: I am not running it in embedded mode as i encountered some problems while trying to follow the documentation which i do not know how to fix, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067168/problems-attempting-to-embed-exist-db/50067876 which is why i resorted to attempting to use it like this